# Moving Wix <UI> to another file

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to split out my wix file into two separate files. With everything that exists under my `<UI> </UI>` tag living in this secondary file.

I have googled this quite a bit but I don't seem to be getting any conclusive results.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Wix project add the reference to the WixUIExtension

In your Product.wxs (Main Install file) add a line like this

```
<UIRef Id="UserInterface"/>
```

Add the UserInterface.wxs to your project solution and customize the UI of your MSI:

```
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title"  FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
  <DialogRef Id="InstallDirDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="FeaturesDlg" />




  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg" Order="2"></Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="FeaturesDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ExitDialog" Order="2">1</Publish>



  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

</UI>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

The complete sample of this code can be found at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367670/wix-3-5-install-features-based-on-checkboxes/9583544#9583544)

Look at this [link](http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/), explains how to create Custom Dialogs

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can move the `<UI>` element with its contents to a separate file easily. Just make sure to reference it from the main `Product.wxs` with [`<UIRef>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_uiref.htm) element.