# WiX: Duplicate symbol 'ControlEvent:ExitDialog/Finish/EndDialog/Return/1' found

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have a WiX 3.8 installer `Product.wxs` that builds correctly in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
I just wanted to experiment with modifying the steps workflow of the installer, so I added the UI block from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310689/226958) just after the Wix/Product/Package XML element:

```
<UI>
  <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Custom" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title"  FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
  
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
  <DialogRef Id="InstallDirDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="FeaturesDlg" />
  
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg" Order="2"></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="FeaturesDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ExitDialog" Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Problem: WiX now fails with this message:

> Error 13  Duplicate symbol 'ControlEvent:ExitDialog/Finish/EndDialog/Return/1' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.   C:\MyApp\Installer\Product.wxs  42  1   Installer
>
> Error 14  Location of symbol related to previous error.   C:\src\wix38\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\WixUI_Minimal.wxs   46  1   Installer

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I had another `<UI>` element later in `Product.wxs` that I did not remember about.

Removing this second `<UI>` block solved the problem.