# Can't set first radio button by default

Tags: wix

I am building an installer that contains two radio buttons within a RadioButtonGroup. I create the property that relates to the radio group and give it a default value of 0 (the first radio button). I also look in the registry to see if a previous install set one of the buttons.

```
<Property Id="MACHINE_TYPE" Value="0" Secure="yes">
        <RegistrySearch Id="ExistingMachineTypeProperty" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" Name="AGENT_MACHINE_TYPE" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<SetProperty Action="UpdateMachineTypeValue" Id="MACHINE_TYPE" After="AppSearch" Value="{}">MACHINE_TYPE="0"</SetProperty>
```

The control element looks like this

```
<Control Id="DbStatsMachineType" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="78" Width="115" Height="50" Property="MACHINE_TYPE">
    <RadioButtonGroup Property="MACHINE_TYPE">
        <RadioButton Value="0" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" Height="15" Text="Machine A" />
        <RadioButton Value="1" X="0" Y="32" Width="300" Height="15" Text="Machine B" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
    <Condition Action="enable">DBSTATSENABLED</Condition>
    <Condition Action="disable">NOT DBSTATSENABLED</Condition>
</Control>
```

I am having issues with setting the first radio button by default. If there is no env var AGENT_MACHINE_TYPE, then neither radio button is selected by default. If the var equals 0, neither radio button is selected. BUT, if the var is 1, then the second radio button is selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the time at which the condition is evaluated in relation to your initial value for MACHINE_TYPE.

I've posted an answer before that deals with this issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328619/wix-conditional-install-of-features-based-on-radio-buttons/40037631#40037631), take a look. Hope it helps you!